# Check if user is a member of group

Tags: users, organic-groups

```
<?php
global $user;
if (in_array($group->nid, $user->og_groups)) {
  print t('Click here to subscribe');
}
else {
  print t('Click here to see other user in this group');
}
?>
```

I am trying to check if user belongs to a group or not.

I got this code in node--group.php . But it wont work.

I get an error:

**Undefined variable: group in include() (line 6....
Trying to get property of non-object in include() (line 6
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$og_groups in include() (line 6 
Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in include() (line 6**

Anyone can help me?

Thank you!

Comment: Does replacing `$group->nid` with `$node->nid` fix it?

Comment: Nope.. Tried that but wont work